# database not affected by dataset after renewing a table

Tags: c#, database, dataset

I have a dataset that contains a table. This table has just a column (without primary key). My table is shown in a datagridview. Now, I want to edit data of table. So, I store data of table in a DataTable and then, I clear all data of table in dataset and fill it by DataTable, like this:

```
DataView dv = ((BindingSource)tblMyTableDataGridView.DataSource).SyncRoot as DataView;
DataTable dt = dv.ToTable();
IDataReader dr = dt.CreateDataReader();
myDataSet.tblMyTable.Clear();
myDataSet.tblMyTable.Load(dr);
```

By breaking point, that specified that tblMyTable has changed truely.
***But it not affected on database***. My code is:

```
tableAdapterManager.tblMyTableTableAdapter.Update(myDataSet.tblMyTable);
tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(myDataSet);
```

What is wrong?!?!?
Thanks.

Comment: have you set an UpdateCommand on the adapter? I have a blog example: https://contrivedexample.com/2017/05/27/c-data-binding-example-with-adapters-and-datagridview/

Comment: No! I don't need to UpdateCommand. I Fill tblMyTable (from dataset) outside of DataSet.

Comment: Are any rows in tblMyTable in the modified state?

Comment: Maybe ... tblMyTable (in dataset) has changed and showed edited data. But database is not changed!!!

Comment: I haven't tried it to be sure, but I think you are losing rowatates when you clear and then load from the reader. It would be easy enough to see in the debugger. But you can make it so much easier by making the dataset a class level field on the form. Since it is wrapped by binding source all you need do is call Update with that field - no dataviews, readers, etc, necessary. That  is what the example I linked to shows.

Comment: OK. It was solved! I cleared all data in database by Delete command (in dataset) and add (Since it is wrapped by binding source all you need do is call Update with that field) rows of datagridview into database by Insert command (in dataset). Thanks @Crowcoder .